# using googletest in eclipse: how?

Tags: c++, eclipse, googletest

I've downloaded google test, but now I've no idea on how to link it to my project in eclipse.
Should I add it as a source folder? Should include it as g++ included library? And how can I run test then?

Comment: Originally, Google recommended linking with a library, but later they changed their recommendation after they had a lot of bad experiences. The library is build using certain compiler options. If the test case and software are not built with identical options, then things can go wrong – either disastrously or subtly. 

So, now they recommend to include the Gtest source code into every test case and build it all as one, not with Gtest as a linked library. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog

Answer (score 42):

Using [Riga's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951808/using-googletest-in-eclipse-how/5800759#5800759), here is a summary of how I got it to work:

1. Created a new C++ project in Eclipse (I chose Executable > Empty Project)
2. Downloaded [googletest 1.5.0](http://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.5.0.tar.bz2), untarred, and ran `./scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py . <project-dir>/contrib`
3. Back in Eclipse, excluded the `contrib` directory from the Release build configuration, and added `<project-dir>/contrib` to the include directories (odd, I know)
4. Added a `src` directory and added a class named `Foo` (see below for the contents of `Foo.h`--I left `Foo.cpp` empty for now)
5. Added a `test` directory in Eclipse, excluded it from the Release build configuration, added `<project-dir>/contrib` to the include directories, and added new source files `FooTest.cpp` and `AllTests.cpp` (see below for contents)
6. Built and ran the project!

Foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
class Foo {
public:
  virtual ~Foo();
  Foo();
  bool foo(void) { return true; }
};
#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

FooTest.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Foo.h"
namespace {
  class FooTest : public ::testing::Test {
  protected:
    Foo foo;
  };
  TEST_F(FooTest, Foo) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(foo.foo());
  }
}
```

AllTests.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "FooTest.cpp"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here are the detailed steps:

1. In Eclipse, open the **File** menu and select **New** > **C++ Project**
2. Project Type: **Executable** > **Empty Project**
3. Toolchain: **Linux GCC**
4. Click **Finish**
5. Open a terminal and `cd /tmp`
6. `wget http://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.5.0.tar.bz2`
7. `cd gtest-1.5.0/`
8. `./scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py . <project-dir>/contrib`
9. Back in Eclipse, right-click on the project folder in the Project Explorer pane, then select **Refresh**
10. In the Project Explorer pane, right-click on the `contrib` folder, select **Exclude from build...*, untick only the **Release** box, and click **OK**
11. Right-click on the `contrib` folder and select **Properties** > **C/C++ Build** > **Settings** > **Tool Settings** tab > **GCC C++ Compiler** > **Directories**
12. Click on the **Add...** button, then the **Workspace...** button, then select `<project-name>/contrib` and click **OK** to add the directory
13. Click **OK** once more to accept your changes to the build settings
14. Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer pane and select **New** > **Folder**, enter `src` as its name, and click **OK**
15. Right-click on the `src` folder in the Project Explorer pane and select **New** > **Class**, name it `Foo`, then click **OK** (see above for contents of `Foo.h`; `Foo.cpp` can be left as is)
16. Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer pane and select **New** > **Folder**, enter `test` as its name, and click **OK**
17. Follow the steps above to add `<project-name>/contrib` and `<project-name>/src` as include directories to the `test` directory
18. Right-click on the `test` folder, then select **New** > **Source File** to add `AllTests.cpp` to the `test` folder, then repeat the same steps to add `FooTest.cpp` (see above for contents)
19. Right-click on `FooTest.cpp` and select **Exclude from build...**, click the **Select All** button, then **OK**
20. Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer pane, and select **Properties** > **C/C++ Build** > **Settings** > **Tool Settings** tab > **GCC C++ Linker** > **Libraries**, then click the **Add...** button, enter **pthread** (required by googletest), click **OK** to add the library, then **OK** once more to accept the changes
21. Hit **Ctrl-b** to build the project
22. Hit **Ctrl-F11** to run the project
23. Victory!

Comment: I have another file in my main src folder (not test/src) which has a main function and the project wont build because AllTests also contains a main function. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I cant see the "Exclude from build" at the step .10. Can you help me?

Comment: I am responding to myself: for my kepler eclipse, you should follow this: right click->properties->c/c++build->settings->exclude...

Comment: in the short description you forgot to add ste 19. You need to add "pthread" to the project libraries.

Comment: where is tmp in windows?

Comment: @Josh In Step 10, shouldn't it be "tick" only the release - instead of "untick" only the release?

Answer (score 32):

**Step 1  Install Eclipse**

If Eclipse is not already installed on the machine, then get the latest version of the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers from the Eclipse downloads page (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

If Eclipse is already installed but only for Java, download the C++ plug-in following these instructions.

a.       Open Eclipse and click on Help->Install New Software

[image]

b.      In the Work with: box, type in http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler. After a few moments, the Name box will populate. Select the following components:

- CDT Main Features -> C/C++ Development Tools
- CDT Main Features -> C/C++ Development Tools SDK
- CDT Optional Features -> C/C++ Unit Testing Support
- CDT Optional Features -> C/C++ Unit Testing Support Source
- CDT Optional Features -> C/C++ Visual C++ Support

[image]

c.       Click on Next, agree to the statements, and then Finish.

**Step 2  Download Cygwin**

Install Cygwin by clicking on the setup-x86_64.exe link on the Cygwin install page (http://www.cygwin.com/install.html). After running, click Next through the defaults until you get to the Select Packages window.

[image]

You will need to search for and install two packages: gcc and make.

The first search term is gcc. Search for gcc and then open the Devel folder. Mark the following packages for install by clicking on the word Skip (it will then change to the build number, which may by higher than the one depicted here): gcc-core, gcc-g++, and libgcc1.

[image]

The second search term is make. Here, we will only need the Devel package make.

[image]

Once these have been selected, click Next to install.

**Step 3  Download and build Google Test project**

Download the latest release of GoogleTest from https://code.google.com/p/googletest/downloads/list, and extract the zip file contents into a common directory. It is important that all users are able to access this directory.

(Note: the following commands use `make` -- the last revision of GoogleTest that uses `make` is https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.8.1. For future revisions of GoogleTest use `cmake` instead.)

To build the Google Test project:

1. Open Cygwin (find the install directory for Cygwin and double-click
   on Cygwin.bat).
2. Change the current working directory to the unzipped
   GoogleTest make directory: `cd c:/<<yourpath>>/gtest-1.7.0/make/`
3. Build the project: `make`
4. Create an archived library out of the
   gtest-all.o file: `ar -rv libgtest.a gtest-all.o`

**Step 4  Add the Cygwin bin directory to the computers PATH variable**

Follow the instructions on this page for your version of Windows: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml, to add Cygwins bin directory to the computers PATH environment variable. (typically by adding ;C:\cygwin64\bin to the end of the current value).

**Step 5  Create a new project that uses GoogleTest**

Start Eclipse and select File->New->C++ Project. Enter the values below and click Finish.

[image]

In the Project Explore, right-click the name of the project and select Properties. Under C/C++ Build, change the Builder type to Internal Builder.

[image]

Under C/C++ Build, select Settings, then click on the Includes folder under Cygwin C++ Compiler. Click on the Add button in the top box and then browse to the GoogleTest include folder.

[image]

Lastly, under the Cygwin C++ Linker folder, select Miscellaneous and then click the Add icon under Other objects. Find the libgtest.a file that you built back in step 3 (it should be in the make directory of the unzipped gtest folder).

[image]

Thats it! Now you're ready to try it out.

**Step 6  Write some code that uses GoogleTest**

- Add a source folder by clicking File->New->Source folder. Call it
  src.
- Add a header file by right-clicking on the src folder and select New->Header File. Call this file Counter.h.
- Add a source file by right-clicking on the src folder and select New->Source File. Call
  this file Counter.cpp.
- Add another source file and call it Counter_Tests.cpp.

Copy and paste the code below into the appropriate files:

*Counter.h*

```
class Counter { 
private: 
      int mCounter;
public:    
      Counter() : mCounter(0) {}  
      int Increment();    
};
```

*Counter.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Counter.h"

int Counter::Increment() {    
      return mCounter++;
}
```

*Counter_Tests.cpp*

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Counter.h"

TEST(Counter, Increment) {
      Counter c;    
      EXPECT_EQ(0, c.Increment());
      EXPECT_EQ(1, c.Increment());
      EXPECT_EQ(2, c.Increment());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
      ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
      return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

In the Project menu select Build All. Now, to connect up the GoogleTest unit testing framework, select Run Configurations from the Run menu. From this dialog, select C/C++ Unit and click the New button.

[image]

It should fill in this project name automatically under C/C++ Application, if not click on Search Project to select this project. Next, click on the C/C++ Testing tab. In the Tests Runner drop-down, choose Google Tests Runner, and then click Run to watch the magic!

[image]

Below is a snapshot of the result. After writing more code/tests, you can click on the button highlighted in red to quickly recompile and re-run all of the tests.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this thorough tutorial. Just one thing, my google test framework **did not** generate **libgtest.a**, so I had to ski; steps 3.4 and the last step of 5. But at the end, everything worked like a charm. thank you again.

Answer (score 10):

You should not add it to your source folder, make separate folder instead. This is for avoidance of dependency of your production code from testing project. Do it like this

```
../ #your project folder
Makefile
src/
  module1 #some module
  module2 #another module
build #tmp for build
dist #binaries 
contrib/
  gtest
  ...
test/ #your test project folder
  Makefile
  src/
    module1 #correspondent to main project's one
    module2 #correspondent to main project's one
  build
  dist
  ...
```

I usually use google test as two files, this is very handy. Use `scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py` from gtest distribution to extract them. Having only two files you can include their compilation in your test project compilation and have simple project structure.

In your test projectspecify include directories `../contrib:../src:src`.
Thus you can include headers like this

test/src/module1/class1Test.h:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "module1/class1.h"

// test class1 here
// ...
```

test/src/mainTest.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "module1/class1Test.h"
#include "module2/class2Test.h"
// include other tests you have
// ...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution for Eclipse 4.3 and CDT 8.2
I felt this was somewhat easier then described above.

1. Download gtest and install it as described in the readme.txt (using cmake and make in linux)
2. Go to "YourProject-> Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings-> GCC C++ Compiler-> Includes-> Include paths" and add the include folder in gtest
3. Go to "YourProject-> Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Settings-> GCC C++ Linker-> Libraries", add the gtest folder as search path and add libraries "gtest" and "pthread"

(4. If you have tests in the same project as sources exclude tests from release build)

1. Go to "Run-> Run Configurations..." and Create a new C/C++ Unit run configuration
2. Set project to your project and C/C++ Application to your Application in main tab. Set Tests Runner to Google Test Runner in C/C++ Testing tab.

(7. Error notifications may stick around in the eclipse gui, if this is the case re-indexing the project might help)

Answer (score 0):

I've tray your solution and it runs well. I can say that for compile gtest is not very clear in the README. txt.

I've run the makefile in the /make directory through a cygwin console.
In my case the compiler advise me that don't findt the pthread library. So I modified the line

`CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread`

and changed it to

`CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -lpthread`

The output I get is `gtest_main.a`. Then I have rename this file into libgtest.a and copy it to `C:\cygwin\lib directory`.

Then i've configure my eclipse project to use cygwin and added gtest and pthread as you say... and it works!

I hope it can help someone